# mysql2 gem will not install properly

Tags: mysql, ruby, installation, rubygems

When I try to manually install the mysql2 gem, I get this crazy mess.
Any help would be very appreciated.

```
littleMac$ sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Are you not using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) yet?

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed? Native gems would fail to build if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to install the mysql header files, so it can compile on your machine.**

On MacOS (I suppose you are on a Mac due to the log), you first install MySQL via binary or Homebrew, *and then* run:

```
gem install mysql2
```

I suggest following the instructions of installing MySQL and Rails on MacOS given [here](http://blog.devinterface.com/2010/09/how-to-install-mysql-and-rails-on-osx-snow-leopard/).

Comment: Thanks Kenny! The issue ended up being that I upgraded to Lion, and I forgot to upgrade XCODE. Once I did that, the gem installed.

Comment: Great, that you could fix it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case was that I needed to upgrade to the newer version of XCODE (v4). I didn't even think to check to see if the GCC compiler was working. Once I fixed that the gem installed.